# Как использовать данные из одной модели в другой?

Tags: asp.net, mvc

У меня есть две таблицы

```
public class TestManagementToolsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test_Case> Test_Cases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test_Suite> Test_Suites { get; set; }
}
```

Как можно использовать в в модели `Test_Suite` `Test_Cases`?

Когда я добавляю список `List<Test_Case>` в `Test_Suite`, то при изменении этого списка с кейсами меняются кейсы и в `Test_Cases`

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var query = db.Test_Cases
            .Include(c => c.StepAndExpResults)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList()
            .Select(c => new Test_Case
        {
            Identifier = c.Identifier,
            Title = c.Title,
            Preconditions = c.Preconditions,
            Date = c.Date,
            Comments = c.Comments,
            Summary = c.Summary,
            StepAndExpResults = c.StepAndExpResults
        }).ToList();

        Test_Suite suite = new Test_Suite();

        suite.all_test_cases = query;

        return View(suite);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,test_cases_ch,all_test_cases,Date")] Test_Suite test_Suite)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < test_Suite.all_test_cases.Count; i++)
            {
                if (test_Suite.all_test_cases[i].check == true)
                {
                    //test_Suite.all_test_cases[i].check = false;

                    if (test_Suite.test_cases_ch == null)
                    {
                        test_Suite.test_cases_ch = new List<Test_Case>();
                    }
                    Test_Case test_case = new Test_Case();
                    test_Suite.test_cases_ch.Add(test_case);
                    test_Suite.test_cases_ch[count] = test_Suite.all_test_cases[i];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            test_Suite.Date = DateTime.Now;
            test_Suite.all_test_cases = null;
            db.Test_Suites.Add(test_Suite);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(test_Suite);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом месте `test_Suite.test_cases_ch[count] = test_Suite.all_test_cases[i];` Вы создаете копию ссылки. Соответственно, изменяя значение `test_Suite.test_cases_ch[count]`, изменяется и `test_Suite.all_test_cases[i]`. Чтобы этого избежать, Вы можете в класс `Test_Case` добавить конструктор. Пока класс представим так:

```
public class Test_Case
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; },
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

конструктор такого вида:

```
public Test_Case(Test_Case t)
{                
   this.Identifier = t.Identifier;
   this.Title = t.Title;
}
```

Или метод `Clone()`:

```
public Test_Case Clone()
{
    Test_Case t = new Test_Case();
    t.Identifier = this.Identifier;
    t.Title = this.Title;
    return t;
}
```

Тогда можно использовать так:

```
Test_Case test_case = new Test_Case(test_Suite.all_test_cases[i]);
test_Suite.test_cases_ch.Add(test_case);
```

или:

```
test_Suite.test_cases_ch[count] = test_Suite.all_test_cases[i].Clone();
```

Это будет работать, если `Test_Case` содержит поля стандартных типов `int`, `string` и т. д. Для полей с собственными типами нужно будет реализовывать метод `Clone()`.